# How do I combine two strings?

Tags: c++, string, strlen

The question requires combining two strings(the longer string in the front and the shorter one after the longer one) without using `<string>` header file.Each string inputted can't exceed 20 characters.
My logic behind this is:

> 1. first use `strlen` to get the length of the `str1` and `str2`,
> 2. use `str3` to store the longer string, and `str4` to store the shorter.
> 3. add `str3` and `str4` to `str5`

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // combine two strings , longer in the front, and shorter 
    // after it. do not use strcat
    char str1[20],str2[20],str3[20],str4[20],str5[40];
    // str1 and str2 stores original data, str3 stores longer 
    // and str4 stores shorter, str5 stores total
    int j=0;
    cin.getline(str1,20);
    cin.getline(str2,20);
    if(strlen(str1)<=strlen(str2))
    // give longer string value to str3,shorter to str2
    {
        for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            str3[i]=str2[i];
            str4[i]=str1[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            str3[i]=str1[i];
            str4[i]=str2[i];
        }
    }
    for(j=0;str3[j]!='\0';j++)
    {
        str5[j]=str3[j];
    }
    for(int i=j;i<40;i++)
    for(int m=0;m<20;m++)
    {
        str5[i]=str4[m];
    }
    cout<<str5<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the ouput:

[image]

What's my problem here? What are those characters in between the two strings? Thank you!!

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `std::string` ?

Comment: the questions asks not to use std::string header,maybe to practice the  loops?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `C` stuff, but have you looked into `strcpy()`?

Comment: I can't use it in this question, I can't include the header `string`. I believe `strcpy()` is in `<string>`.

Comment: Is that a c++ or c course?

Comment: strcpy is in string.h, but then so is strlen

Comment: yes, I am watching videos from coursera. The course has ended when I subscribed, so I can't ask questions through the course forum.

Comment: `string.h` and `string` are two different files. You can't use either?

Comment: @David Sykes, strlen works with only iostream in my code

Comment: @olevegard, the original words are not to use strcpy or strcat. I really want to find out where I went wrong in my code, and how to fix it. I will try the other ways once I figure this one out. I haven't touched any other header files except iostream and stdio.h yet, so it could be a little bit challenging.

Comment: @user3858 normally strlen, strcpy and strcat are all in the same `.h` file.

Comment: @user3858 in my opinion if you don't want to use them you better write them youself (+ it's really easy) than to drown yourself in writing them for particular cases.

Comment: Note that my answer points out where your code is failing

Comment: @Dieter Lücking it is called c++ course

Comment: Note that everything you have written is C, except for 'cout<<str5<<endl;'

Comment: @DavidSykes Is there explicit border between c and c++? How compatible are they? Isn't solving the problem the primary reason for using programming language?

Comment: The differences are quite complex, but in essence c++ includes all of c, and extends it with objects. As a learner you would be better off with c++ and using the standard library, which is why people are suggesting you use std::string and not char*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is fine (!) up to this point

```
for(int i=j;i<40;i++)
for(int m=0;m<20;m++) // This loop runs m=0 to 20 for each position of i
{
    str5[i]=str4[m];
}
```

For each index i you are copying in all 20 elements from str4, leaving just the value at str4[19] which could be anything

Just increment i and m by one together

```
int m = 0;
for(int i=j;i<40;i++)
{
    str5[i]=str4[m++];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Especially since you explicitly mentioned being a beginner, the solution is to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string a;
    getline(std::cin, a);

    std::string b;
    getline(std::cin, b);

    // Ensure that the longer string goes to the front.
    if (a.size() < b.size());
        swap(a, b);

    std::string result = a + b;

    std::cout << result << '\n';

    // Or, simply:
    std::cout << a << b << '\n';
}
```

The message here is that C++, despite its quirks, is a very high level language if you rely on its library instead of implementing every low level operation from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You are copying the entire 20 characters, 40 characters in the loop into the variables. stop copying when you find a '\0' character.

But using the std::string will make life simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `std::string` is nice and all but here's a few tips for working with `char*`:

1) You shouldn't copy strings to separate shorter and longer string, just use pointers and then work with these pointers, something along these lines:

```
const char *longer_string = 0, *shorter_string = 0;
if(strlen(str1)<=strlen(str2))
   {
     shorter_string = str1;
     longer_string = str2;
   }
 else
   {
     shorter_string = str2;
     storter_string = str1;
   }
```

2) Using strcpy and strcat to combine strings could make life a lot easier:

```
    char *combined_string = new char [strlen (shorter_string) + strlen (longer_string) + 1];
    strcpy (combined_string, longer_string);
    strcat (combined_string, shorter_string);
```

Some compilers would say that these functions aren't safe and you have to stick to `_s` versions, but I guess it's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is obviously homework: I'll just point out the existence of the function `strcat`, and the fact that you can use `char*` to the arrays, and just swap them, without having to recopy anything between the initial read and the concatenation (which means that you only need two arrays: one for each of the inputs, and one for the final value).

And also, when calculating sizes, etc. do not forget that C style strings have an extra `'\0'` at the end, and make allowances for it.

Answer (score 1):

As @David Sykes has pointed out, the problem is with your for loop. So when you read input from **cin** ,it is not necessary that your input string contains 20 character. But in you form loop you are looping through those string beyond their length which may contains garbage characters. Example

```
char str1[20]
 cin.getline(str1,20);
 cout << str1[19] << endl;
```

Suppose your input for above code is "ABCD" which contains only 4 characters but your array has capacity of 20. So the remaining space has junk characters and when you will try to print any thing beyond actual length you will get wild character as you are getting in your code.